Breakpoint in a callback function from iPyWidgets Jupiter Notebook not breaking in VsCode
I created a Jupyter Notebook cell with this code
from ipywidgets import widgets

def test_fun(button):
    for i in range(10): # breakpoint in this line
        print(i)

# Button to split in 12 months
test_button = widgets.Button(description="Click Me!")
test_button.on_click(test_fun)
display(test_button)

Then I set a breakpoint in "for i in range(10)". I expected the debugger to start when I clicked the test_button, but that didn't happen. You can see in the screenshot the cycle runs uninterrupted.

I tried this in JupyterLabs without a problem. I also tried the jupyter.debugJustMyCode": false option, although it doesn't seem applicable to this case.
Also, breakpoints outside the test_fun work as expected.
Versions:

Visual Studio Code: 1.95.3
jupyter_server: 2.14.2
ipywidgets: 8.1.1


I don't have a definitive answer or solution at all, but I wonder if it is like this case discussed here where because you put it inside a widget the signal needed by the debugger isn't propagated to where the debugger expects and it fails? I know that other one I point out appears unrelated because the debugging approaches are very different but I wonder if the underlying issue is similar.

I did find that and tried to use an Output widget, without success. But yes, maybe there's some connection.

Thanks for noting you tried that.
